# how to get current activity from stack activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-context, activity-stack

I want to get current activity from activity stack and replace with `??????`

```
dialog =new AlertDialog.Builder(??????,android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert).setTitle("Tittle").setMessage("Message");`
```

How Can I Do it?

**Update1 :**

I can't use `getContext()` or `getActivty` because they return `null`

Also I find this

```
ActivityManager am =(ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

ComponentName cn = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity;
```

I dont know how to use `cn` to conver to a `context` or `Activity` ?

Please help me!!!

Comment: If you are looking for a context object, you can use `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: The ide don`t let me to use it

Comment: is your `new AlertDialog.Builder` inside fragment

Comment: "I can't use getContext() or getActivty because they return null" -- then you have your code in the wrong place. "I dont know how to use cn to conver to a context or Activity ?" -- you can't.

Comment: yes its inside a fragment

Comment: `cn` show name of my activity true but its a String if there is  a way to convert this String to Activity Object or get current Activity from Activity stack my problem solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Context context;
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    this.context = context;
}
```

then

```
dialog =new AlertDialog.Builder(context,android.R.style.Theme_Material_Dialog_Alert).setTitle("Tittle").setMessage("Message");`
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer but its may change my activity before execute `dialog =new AlertDialog.Builder...`

Comment: Yes your Answer is Correct but `dialog` show with some delay So The user can click on back button to go back to last Activity(So application may crash)

Comment: it show this Error `Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@ee76728 is not valid; is your activity running?`

Comment: You need to figure out why your dialog causing a delay while launching

Comment: for backpress issue though its not a good solution you can maintain some `flag` for `onbackpressed` to decide whether to finish actvity or not when dialog show event is triggered